# Can I install/upgrade from SL to Lion on RAID0?

Tags: macos, upgrade, install, mac-pro, raid

I have a 2007 Mac Pro with a 3-disk RAID0 bootdrive.

I want to do a clean Lion install on the RAID volume but I'm not sure if there are any known issues with doing this. I seem to remember that last time I did something like this the installer crapped-out when it encountered the RAID. I got round this by doing a clean install on a different (single) drive, backing it up and then reinstalling it onto the RAID volume. Quite painful.

I understand that I'll have to create the Recovery HD on an external drive but this aside, does anyone have any knowledge they can share? I'm *hoping* that the lack of info online means that its perfectly fine and I'm worrying unduly ;-)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a hardware RAID card or simply the software RAID that all Mac OS have?

Comment: Software RAID. All seems to have gone smoothly. Keeping my fingers crossed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you should be fine. I upgraded to Lion on a Mac Pro that has a RAID 0. While the OS is installed to an SSD, not RAID, Lion still detected the RAID just fine. That's obviously a different scenario than what you have, but as the software RAID is handled at a higher level than the OS, I think you should be fine.

Obviously, have a backup ready to go just in case, but my guess is that your upgrade should go smoothly.

Comment: That's all I needed to know, starting the install now. Many thanks!

Comment: That all went astonishingly smoothly. I should stop being so cowardly, I really should. Thanks again.